# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence while fitting data to svm

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf

I have dataset as follows:

```
 text  size   bold   label
 xxxx    5     1      0.0
 yyyy   15     0      1.0
  .      .     .       . 
  .      .     .       .
```

where label is target variable, text column is having string and bold and size  are having int and label is having float.

Now I have convert text column to array using tf-idf vectorizer.

```
data['tf_idf_q1'] = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(data["text"])
```

Now for training and testing I'm using 3  and 1 column respectively:

```
X = data[['tf_idf_q1', 'size', 'bold']].as_matrix()
y = data['label'].as_matrix()
```

Now when I try to fit data to svm model:

```
clf = svm.LinearSVC().fit(X, y)
```

It's showing me error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I tried to convert my X and y to dtype=float but it's not working.

I'm new to nlp and all please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

created dummy dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text  import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()

df = pd.DataFrame([['hi how are you',5],['hope this help you',4],['gd mrng',3]], columns=['sent','size'])
df['tf_idf_q1'] = tfidf.fit_transform(df["sent"])

df['tf_idf_q1'].as_matrix()

#o/p , which is not a number and you are getting error

array([<3x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
   <3x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
   <3x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

convert above sparse matrix to dense representation..

```
text_feature_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf.fit_transform(df["sent"]).todense(), columns = tfidf.get_feature_names()) 

df_size_text = pd.concat([text_feature_df,df],axis = 1)
```

now pass data of df_size_text  into your model, and drop columns df['tf_idf_q1']